# Why are my bootstrap 3 glyphicons so wide?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why my glyphicons are taking up the majority of my input box. I am using bootstrap 3.0 and here is a screenshot of what I am looking at.

[image: Glyphicon Issue]

Here is how I have them set up:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label style="font-size:12px;">Time Ended</label>
    <div  class="input-group" id="datetimepicker2" >

      <input type="text" name="time_ended" class="form-control" value="" />
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:10px;">
        <span class="glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: inspect the element and see where the width property is being set

Comment: you probably have a CSS that's affecting the size. try removing your custom CSS and just include the bootstrap only.

You should consider using font-awesome icons. I think bootstrap 4 will do away with glyphicons.

Comment: I thank you QBM5. Inspecting the element I was able to track it down and fix the issue. I appreciate the help. Could you promote this to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you might be missing the base class:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
```